# Supabase JS missing "DELETE" event

Tags: javascript, supabase, supabase-database

Here is a snippet of my code

```
const subscription = supabase
            .from(`messages:channel_id=eq.${props.channelId}`)
            .on('INSERT', payload => addMessage(payload.new))
            .on('UPDATE', payload => updateMessage(payload.new))
            .on('DELETE', payload => removeMessage(payload.old))
            .subscribe()
```

with the `messages` table having enabled [realtime](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/api#managing-realtime) as well as [full replication](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/subscribe#listening-to-deletes) with currently no `RLS` enabled for testing purposes.

But I only receive `UPDATE` and `INSERT` events, if I delete a row in the `messages` table, nothing happens (I don't receive any event when logging with `console.log`).

**How can I also receive `DELETE` events?**

Answer (score 1):

If you want to receive "previous" data for updates and deletions, you will need to set REPLICA IDENTITY to FULL, like this: ALTER TABLE your_table REPLICA IDENTITY FULL;

if help everyone ;-)